# Load javascript function from variable name

Tags: javascript, function

How do I load a javascript function from a variable name. For example:

```
var variable = 'world';

function helloworld()
{
 // blah
}

// I want to load helloword();
hello + variable + ();
```

How would I load `helloworld()` function like this?

Comment: Why don't you do hello(variable) instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `helloworld` function is defined in [global scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window), then use:

```
window["hello" + variable]();
```

Comment: @David It works if you change the scope from `onLoad` of `MooTools`: http://jsfiddle.net/k6FsU/1/.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many functions you have, you could do this:

```
var variable = "world"

var hello = {
  world : function() { /* Function contents */ },
  cat   : function() { /* Function contents */ },
  food  : function() { /* Function contents */ },
  …
}

hello[variable]();
```